# How to display 1 instead of 01 in ToString();

Tags: c#, formatting, string

I am using the format ToString("0,0") to display a number like

```
5000 as 5,000
```

but if the number is 0 - 9, it displays 01, 02, 03, etc.  Does anyone know the correct syntax so it does not display the leading 0?

Thanks,
XaiSoft

Comment: Is that comma at the end of 5,000, for the sentence or the number? :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ToString("#,0")
```

Also, [this](http://acodingfool.typepad.com/blog/dotnet-string-formatting-cheat-sheet.html) may help you further

Comment: He, thanks. I just found it today, it has a lot more also very useful

Comment: cheat sheet link broken :(

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the string formatter "N0".  Example:

```
int x = 10000;
int y = 5;

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("N0"));
Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("N0"));
```

Prints:

```
10,000
5
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
ToString("N0")
```

Comment: On first sight, I thought this was a humorous answer saying "No, I don't know how to...". Then I realised that Oh was a Zero...